# is bayesian poisson regression remotely relevant in this scenario?

Tags: bayesian, mixed-model, poisson-regression, demography

I am working with data collected in a community. We know the basic information about the community, let's say the racial composition is 60% black and 40% white, in a city of population = 500,000. I now have a list of incidents (fewer than 200 of them in total). Let's assume people involved in these incidents are either black or white. I want to be able to test if probability of a racial group involved in these incidents are unusually high/low, considering the racial composition that we know of this city. We don't have data for people who are NOT involved.

My question is: what tests should I use? I recently attended a talk about bayesian analysis so I'm leaning that direction. Given the small number of incidents perhaps poisson regression will be more appropriate?

Also, these incidents happened in different neighborhood, maybe 10-15 each neighborhood. It seems we need to rely on some mixed effect modeling. Is this right?

Or I may be overthinking.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Does your data contain all the incidents that happen or was collected randomly? If it wasn't, you have no guarantee that it isn't biased and useless as such.

Comment: Hi Time, it was all the data collected reported by the city

Comment: Then the only thing you can say about it is how often such incidents are *registered*, not how often they happen. If for some reason there is a racial bias in reporting or registering them, the data is useless to show how often do they happen and if there are any racial differences.

Comment: I agree. What would be your recommended test for that, given the characteristics of data I have?

Comment: Get better data.

Comment: wow, I could not have hoped for a more helpful response. Thanks.

Comment: But that's often the only good answer in such cases. Image an extreme example of 100% racist police that registers all the incidents by black people and none of the incidents of white people. At best, such data would tell you about the count of incidents by black people, but you still wouldn't know if there is no false positives and what fraction of the incidents were not registered because not being detected.